# Logical indexing in python for nd arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to extract all the indexes from an `(N x N x N)` numpy array, where values in both A and B arrays are equal to some value `x` - find the common overlap.

I am trying:

```
   A[A==1 and B==1]
```

but get an error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

How do I get around this?

Comment: perhaps slightly hasty posting this question. Used numpy's logical_and(x1, x2[, out])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy cannot overload the "and" keyword. However it overloads the binary AND operator & for this. Try:

A[(A==1) & (B==1)]

The parantheses are important. I find it often (not always)better readable then logical_and

Comment: Thanks! i also found numpy has its own set of logical functions (as below) but this is very useful to know!!

Answer (score 1):

`A == 1` and `B == 1` are boolean arrays, while `(A==1)*(B==1)` is an array of integers. You can find the nonzero entries of this array through NumPy's [`where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where):

```py
np.where((A==1)*(B==1))
```

#### Demo

Consider the following 3-dimensional arrays, which are randomly populated with values `-1`, `0` and `1`:

```py
In [1066]: import numpy as np

In [1067]: np.random.seed(2016)  # this is to get the same results on multiple runs

In [1068]: N = 3
      ...: A = np.random.randint(low=-1, high=2, size=(N, N, N))
      ...: B = np.random.randint(low=-1, high=2, size=(N, N, N))

In [1069]: A
Out[1069]: 
array([[[ 1,  1,  0],
        [-1,  1, -1],
        [-1, -1, -1]],

       [[ 0,  1,  1],
        [-1,  1,  1],
        [ 0,  1,  0]],

       [[ 0,  1,  0],
        [-1,  1,  1],
        [-1,  1,  0]]])

In [1070]: B
Out[1070]: 
array([[[-1,  0,  0],
        [-1, -1,  1],
        [ 0, -1, -1]],

       [[-1, -1, -1],
        [-1,  1,  1],
        [-1,  1,  1]],

       [[ 1,  1, -1],
        [-1,  0,  1],
        [-1,  1, -1]]])
```

The function `where` returns a tuple of integer arrays which triggers [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html?highlight=advanced%20indexing#advanced-indexing):

```py
In [1071]: idx = np.where((A==1)*(B==1))

In [1072]: idx
Out[1072]: 
(array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1], dtype=int64))

In [1073]: A[idx]
Out[1073]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])

In [1074]: B[idx]
Out[1074]: array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps slightly hasty posting this question. Used numpy's

```
logical_and(x1, x2[, out])
```

in the end which did the job perfectly!